# How can I solve the MongoDB Overflow sort stage error?

Tags: c#, mongodb, overflow, mongodb-query

I am using the MongoDB 2.6.7 in Windows 7 (64 bit) with MongoDB C# Driver 1.10.0 and I am facing the following error:

> MongoDB.Driver.MongoQueryException: QueryFailure flag was getMore runner error: Overflow sort stage buffered data usage of 33554527 bytes exceeds internal limit of 33554432 bytes (response was { "$err" : "getMore runner error: Overflow sort stage buffered data usage of 33554527 bytes exceeds internal limit of 33554432 bytes", "code" : 17406 }).

The query I run in C# is:

```
var query = Query<User>.EQ(c => c.GroupId, groupId);

return Collection.Find(query)
                 .SetSortOrder(SortBy.Ascending(User.ID))
                 .SetSkip(page * records)
                 .SetLimit(records)
                 .ToList();
```

I am using an single index for GroupId property and also the ID (with _id value) property has the default index.

I see that there is a related bug in the MongoDB:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-14174

How can I solve this error?

Comment: The server issue you've highlighted isn't really related. The error you are encountering indicates too much data (>32Mb) for an [in-memory sort](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#Sorted-Documents). Adding an appropriate index should resolve this. It looks like your User collection should have a compound index on `{ groupId:1, _id:1}`.

Comment: Sorry, I have used the combound key with inversed order: { _id:1, groupid:1} and it didn't worked. I did it in your order { groupId:1, _id:1} and it worked! Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The server issue you've highlighted isn't really related. The error you are encountering indicates too much data (>32Mb) for an in-memory sort. Adding an appropriate index should resolve this. It looks like your User collection should have a compound index on `{ groupId:1, _id:1}`.

Order in compound keys is definitely important. For some helpful background reading see: [Optimizing MongoDB Compound Indexes](http://emptysqua.re/blog/optimizing-mongodb-compound-indexes/).